# jQuery: Triggering event on dblclick not working (but working on keyup etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, double-click

I am new to JS / jQuery and use the following snippet in my document ready to **call a function on keyup on TDs with a certain class:**

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.calcInOut, .calcBalance', calculateSumsKPR);
```

The function calculates some data based on inputs in the table and then updates cells with the results of the calculations. 
The table is a standard HTML table with a large number of dynamically added rows and TDs and all editable TDs contain a contenteditable div where users can enter numbers.

So far everything works as intended but **for some reason I cannot call the same function on double click**.

I tried using `'dblclick keyup'` instead of `'keyup'` and also tried copying the whole snippet and replacing `keyup` by `dblclick` there but both don't trigger the function on double click.

I do have another event on double click that is initiated separately and clears the div's content on double click but **shouldn't I be able to call two separate events on this** ?

**Example TD:**

```
<td class="calcInOut editable"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>
```

Many thanks for any help with this, 
Mike

Comment: You can only use one event identifier on jquery event binding calls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have options here...

It seems you may have tried to overload the event bind, that won't work.

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
$(object).on("click dblclick keyup", function() { /*do stuff*/ })

$(object).bind("click dblclick keyup", function() { /*do stuff*/ })
```

**DOES WORK**

```
$(object).on("click", function() { /*do stuff*/ }).on("dblclick", function() { /*do stuff*/ }).on("keyup", function() { /*do stuff*/ });

$(object).bind("click", function() { /*do stuff*/ }).on("dblclick", function() { /*do stuff*/ }).on("keyup", function() { /*do stuff*/ });
```

OR

```
$(object).click(function() { /*do stuff*/ }).dblclick(function() { /*do stuff*/ }).keyup(function() { /*do stuff*/ });
```

**ALSO**

Assumably your events all want to fire the same process/method/procedure...

Then you would do this:

```
function doStuff() {
/*do stuff*/
}

$(object).on("click", doStuff).on("dblclick", doStuff).on("keyup", doStuff);
```

OR

```
$(object).bind("click", doStuff).on("dblclick", doStuff).on("keyup", doStuff);
```

OR

```
$(object).click(doStuff).dblclick(doStuff).keyup(doStuff);
```

Comment: This is awesome - thanks a lot ! You are right, I did use one of the approaches you list as not working. Instead I now tried the first of your suggestions which works great ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: Just one question to make sure I get it right, can I use $(document)... here since the table is created dynamically ?

Comment: Any DOM object can be used inside the jquery Selector $().. so yea, $(document) should work. $('body') works as well, as $("#id") or $(".class") where id/class are the respective id or class you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(".js-double-click").dblclick(function() {
  alert("Handler for .dblclick() called.");
});
```

Here is a working codepen: http://codepen.io/socketwiz/pen/OVQdqK?